# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline: change default URL (/assets)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to know if there is a way to change the default URL of the new asset pipeline location in Rails 3.1.
- Default URL is /assets
- I would like to change this to something like /static

My problem is that I already have an Asset model and it might interfere with the URL.

I know that there is a way to specify a different host for the assets (config.asset_host), but I'd rather prefer not to resort to that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In *config/application.rb*, below

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

you can add :

```
config.assets.prefix = "static"
```

That's it :)

Comment: Awesome, @Clément. Thanks!

It looks like it's still buggy though: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1489
The helpers don't respect the custom value. However, the content is indeed available in the new URL. Let's hope it gets fixed soon!

Comment: You're welcome! Indeed I just accessed the assets via URL but no via an helper in my test for you :) Thanks for pointing this issue out, I'm afraid I can't do anything but I'll take a look at it :)

Comment: I guess you saw the update on the issue https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/2684f17a17e4f97bdb89d20b4cd08585235263a2